# Can git read the proxy settings from the default browser?

Tags: git

Windows 7

I write a proxy in the `%HomePath%\.gitconfig` file:

```
[http]
    proxy = http://<Login>:<Password>@<Proxy>:<Port>

[https]
    proxy = https://<Login>:<Password>@<Proxy>:<Port>
```

It works fine, but it is unsafe. I don't want to write my password into text file. Can I tell to `git` to read a proxy settings from the default browser settings?

Comment: Sure: use an encrypted credential helper: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18362082/6309

Comment: And the https proxy url is likely to use an http url, not an https one.